# Can I set up sprinklers with my Sump Pump?

Tags: sump-pump, sprinkler-system, irrigation

I have a MEDAS 1/2HP 1850 GPH submersible pump. I want to use it to water my garden.

Sprinklers sounds good but I worry if I'll have enough water pressure. I was able to connect the pump to a garden hose with a spray nozzle and it looked like good pressure. But spread out over multiple sprinklers across the garden, which is about 30 feet long and 5 feet wide, I'm not sure.

If anyone knows anything about pumps and/or sprinklers, is my pump good enough to set up sprinklers? If so, would you have any advise on implementation?

Comment: Do you have a pond or well to feed water to the pump?  If you're just using residential utility supply but don't have enough pressure, you are better off adding zones with fewer heads per zone.   You should experiment, first with a few sprinkler heads without a pump, then with your sump pump, and build from there.  The parts aren't expensive so experimenting and building incrementally can work.

Answer (score 3):

Your pump is designed for high flow at low pressure. The pump specs quote a maximum 19.5 foot head, and head specs are usually at minimal or zero flow. A 19.5 foot head is the same as 8.5 psi. (2.31 feet of lift requires 1 psi.)

However, presumably your sump pump is below the level of your sprinklers, so you'll lose additional head. If the sump water level is 6 feet below the level of the sprinklers, the maximum pressure will be 5.8 psi.

So how well will your sprinklers work at 5.8 psi? What is their design pressure specification?

Clearly, some water will come out of the sprinklers but they may not sprinkle very far.